# Transpose from long to wide with pair groups in r

Tags: r, transpose

I have descriptive statistics for four groups. My sample dataset is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Grade =  c(3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
  group = c("none","G1","G2","both","none","G1","G2","both"),
  mean=c(10,12,13,12,11,18,19,20),
  sd=c(22,12,22,12,11,13,14,15),
  N=c(35,33,34,32,43,45,46,47))

> df
  Grade group mean sd  N
1     3   none   10 22 35
2     3     G1   12 12 33
3     3     G2   13 22 34
4     3   both   12 12 32
5     4   none   11 11 43
6     4     G1   18 13 45
7     4     G2   19 14 46
8     4   both   20 15 47
```

I would like to compare groups as pairs and need the descriptive information side by side for each pair.

Here is what I would like to have:

[image]

So, each grade has 6 pairs of groups.

Does anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) sqldf** We can join df to itself on the indicated condition. Note that we escaped `group` since `group` is an sql keyword.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select 
  a.Grade, 
  a.[group] Group1, b.[group] Group2,
  a.mean mean1, b.mean mean2,
  a.sd sd1, b.sd sd2,
  a.N n1, b.N n2
from df a
join df b on a.Grade = b.Grade and a.[group] > b.[group]')
```

giving:

```
   Grade Group1 Group2 mean1 mean2 sd1 sd2 n1 n2
1      3   none     G1    10    12  22  12 35 33
2      3   none     G2    10    13  22  22 35 34
3      3   none   both    10    12  22  12 35 32
4      3     G2     G1    13    12  22  12 34 33
5      3   both     G1    12    12  12  12 32 33
6      3   both     G2    12    13  12  22 32 34
7      4   none     G1    11    18  11  13 43 45
8      4   none     G2    11    19  11  14 43 46
9      4   none   both    11    20  11  15 43 47
10     4     G2     G1    19    18  14  13 46 45
11     4   both     G1    20    18  15  13 47 45
12     4   both     G2    20    19  15  14 47 46
```

**2) base R** We can perform a merge on part of the condition and then subset it for the remainder.  The names are slightly different so you will need to change them if that is important.

```
subset(merge(df, df, by = "Grade"), group.x > group.y)
```

giving:

```
   Grade group.x mean.x sd.x N.x group.y mean.y sd.y N.y
2      3    none     10   22  35      G1     12   12  33
3      3    none     10   22  35      G2     13   22  34
4      3    none     10   22  35    both     12   12  32
8      3      G1     12   12  33    both     12   12  32
10     3      G2     13   22  34      G1     12   12  33
12     3      G2     13   22  34    both     12   12  32
18     4    none     11   11  43      G1     18   13  45
19     4    none     11   11  43      G2     19   14  46
20     4    none     11   11  43    both     20   15  47
24     4      G1     18   13  45    both     20   15  47
26     4      G2     19   14  46      G1     18   13  45
28     4      G2     19   14  46    both     20   15  47
```

Comment: When I run the `base` solution, I get this error. `Warning message:
In Ops.factor(group.x, group.y) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors` . Should i change anything?

Comment: In the `df` you posted `group` is character, not factor, under R 4.0+ .  If you have some other data frame that you did not show or if you are using an older version of R where it is factor then just change it to character or to ordered (i.e. oredered factor).

Comment: yes, that was it. Great catch. Thanks for your time and solution. really appreciated!